# PKG_CONFIG_PATH error when installing nautilus RPM on Fedora 15

Tags: linux, path, package

I'm trying to install nautilus RPM in Fedora 15.

```
configure: error: Library requirements (libnautilus >= 2.0.0 gtk+-2.0 >= 2.0.0)
not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable 
if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.
```

I already installed the nautilus package with apt-get install.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Add)

What I want to install is nautilus RPM(GUI RPM management software) and

What I installed is nautilus package.

Comment: If you've already installed the prebuilt package, why are you now trying to build it from source? and why would you use `apt-get` to install the package on a Fedora system? `yum` is the package installer on Fedora.

Comment: @JamesWilcox Thank you for change my question properly.

Comment: @TomH I add some comment for my question. Sorry about ambigous question.

Comment: Problem is in another place. Name of the nautilus file in my fedora is 'nautilus-extension', so ./configure find it. After modifying file name to 'nautilus', it works.

Comment: @TomH I use yum for package installer from now on. Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build software that uses nautilus, then you will need to install the `nautilus-devel` package.